# ObjectDataSource - Can your load methods reside in a different class to the entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, service-layer

I have the following class model:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name;
  public int Age;
}

public class PersonService
{
  public List<Person> GetAll() {...}
}
```

I'm displaying the data on an ASP.Net web page by binding an ObjectDataSource (ODS) to a GridView.

If I point the 'ODS.TypeName = PersonService' then it gives an "Object does not match target type." error on loading data.

If I point the 'ODS.TypeName = Person' then it can't find the GetAll() method to load data.

Is it possible to bind the ODS to this model (i.e. separate classes for the method and type)?

Edit: I've double checked Type and Select method names are correct (and fully qualified).  I made a separate quick test project to prove ODS works with the above model - it does.  The only difference now, is that the broken project is using an Entity defined by EF 4.1 - would that cause a problem?

Answer (score 2):

`TypeName` needs to be set to `PersonService` in your example. There is no need to provide the ODS with the exact type of object bound to the grid's rows (`Person` in your example), as neither ASP.NET data binding nor the ODS/grid will really care. Concerning your error, try to fully qualify the service, e.g., `My.Namespace.PersonService`, and make sure to set `SelectMethod` on the ODS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a PersonList class that exposes a list of Person object and which has a method uses PersonService to populate/return a list.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLhnK.jpg)

Just right click on your project and select "Disable Lightweight Solution Load"
it will work. there is no other issue